# Can we set the $JSON::PP::canonical to sort keys in the output encoded data?

Tags: json, perl

```
use JSON::PP qw(encode_json);

my $json = JSON::PP->new->canonical->allow_nonref;
my $encoded = $json->encode($somehash);

# I would like to use the one-liner code below.
my $json = encode_json($somehash);

# Can I set properties like these? Which one is correct?
$JSON::PP::P_CANONICAL = 1;
$JSON::PP::P_ALLOW_NONREF = 1;
# or
$JSON::PP::canonical = 1;
$JSON::PP::allow_nonref = 1;
```

I want to use the simple encode_json() function.
Can we set the canonical and allow_nonref properties?
Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But nothing stops you from creating your own sub.

```perl
sub my_encode_json {
   return JSON::PP->new->canonical->allow_nonref->encode( $_[0] );
}
```

or

```perl
sub my_encode_json {
   state $encoder = JSON::PP->new->canonical->allow_nonref;
   return $encoder->encode( $_[0] );
}
```